# Pyqt5 : RangeSlider object

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm searching to integrate a RangeSlider into my GUI ( pyqt5 python ) 
Same this picture :

[image]

I search only a easy example.

I find different exemples : 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html but it's a QML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is kind of example what you want.

and I just revised below link's example.

[Maximum value of QSlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218702/maximum-value-of-qslider)

```
# slide Bar Range example.
# max min interval + date example.

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


MAXVAL = 650000

class RangeSliderClass(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.minTime = 0
        self.maxTime = 0
        self.minRangeTime = 0
        self.maxRangeTime = 0

        self.sliderMin = MAXVAL
        self.sliderMax = MAXVAL

        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, RangeSlider):
        RangeSlider.setObjectName("RangeSlider")
        RangeSlider.resize(1000, 65)
        RangeSlider.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 65))
        self.RangeBarVLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(RangeSlider)
        self.RangeBarVLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 0, 5, 0)
        self.RangeBarVLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.RangeBarVLayout.setObjectName("RangeBarVLayout")

        self.slidersFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(RangeSlider)
        self.slidersFrame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 25))
        self.slidersFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.slidersFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.slidersFrame.setObjectName("slidersFrame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.slidersFrame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(5, 2, 5, 2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        ## Start Slider Widget
        self.startSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.slidersFrame)
        self.startSlider.setMaximum(self.sliderMin)
        self.startSlider.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 5))
        self.startSlider.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 10))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setKerning(True)

        self.startSlider.setFont(font)
        self.startSlider.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.startSlider.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.startSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.startSlider.setInvertedAppearance(True)
        self.startSlider.setObjectName("startSlider")
        self.startSlider.setValue(MAXVAL)
        self.startSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.handleStartSliderValueChange)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.startSlider)

        ## End Slider Widget
        self.endSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.slidersFrame)
        self.endSlider.setMaximum(MAXVAL)
        self.endSlider.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 5))
        self.endSlider.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 10))
        self.endSlider.setTracking(True)
        self.endSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.endSlider.setObjectName("endSlider")
        self.endSlider.setValue(self.sliderMax)
        self.endSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.handleEndSliderValueChange)

        #self.endSlider.sliderReleased.connect(self.handleEndSliderValueChange)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.endSlider)

        self.RangeBarVLayout.addWidget(self.slidersFrame)

        #self.retranslateUi(RangeSlider)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(RangeSlider)

        self.show()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def handleStartSliderValueChange(self, value):
        self.startSlider.setValue(value)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def handleEndSliderValueChange(self, value):
        self.endSlider.setValue(value)




app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
awindow = RangeSliderClass()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

running this code.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually produce a range slider, each slider can only access half the range